# what kinds of design patterns to be used for for refreshing the front end?

Tags: rest, microservices

I want to write REST service where front end(app) communicating with it. One of the functionality is user should click a "Refresh Button" only thrice a day. After that button should be disabled. It will be activated the next day.
What is the better way to implement it? On front end? or at REST service?

Tried implementing on back end but with total number of users is quite high, back end job could run for a longer time or may fail..